# How to address multiple tooltips from SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, accessibility

I have an SVG with a title element, as well as polygons with their own empty titles in the hopes of preventing the parent title from appearing when hovering over the polygons because I have a custom JavaScript tooltip for the polygons. So something like

```
<svg aria-labelledby="title1">
<title id = "title1">My big title</title>
<polygon aria-labelledby="title2"></polygon>
// this title element is dynamically generated by JS after the rest of the SVG is added to page
<title id="title2"></title>
</svg>
```

The SVG is generated dynamically from a library and I use JavaScript to append the blank title to remove the main title tooltip from polygons, but after running the JavaScript the tooltip still appears even though the new blank titles are in the DOM.

If I go into the developer tools and edit HTML, but make no changes and then hover over the polygons only the custom tooltip displays as expected. It seems that the JavaScript code adds the blank titles but the browser is cacheing the previous aria data state. Is there any way to use JavaScript to force the browser to reevaluate the aria metadata? I've tried basic things like adding and removing classes

Edit:

```
<svg  viewBox="0 0 20 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <rect id="rect1" x="11" y="1" width="8" height="8">
  </rect>
</svg>

var newtitle=document.createElement("title")
newtitle.innerText = "Title 2"
$("#rect1").append(newtitle)
```

I need the title in the parent SVG for Aria screen reader purposes, but don't want the tooltip to appear because it clashes with JS tooltip. I create a sep title for the polygon/rect object so that it can have its own blank title (or non blank for this example just to see it's not changing) but when I hover over rects I get parent title still. If I don't use JavaScript but create the SVG with a title in the rect manually it works as expected ie

```
<svg  viewBox="0 0 20 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title>Title 1</title>
  <rect id="rect1" x="11" y="1" width="8" height="8">
  <title>Title 2</title>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

This works but adding the second title with JS doesn't

Comment: It’s hard to follow this approach, and what you mean with ARIA data? Are you inspecting the ARIA properties in your browser? What are you trying to achieve in terms of ARIA, it’s not necessarily related to the tooltip content. Maybe you could provide an interactive code example to explain?

Comment: The browser is not taking into consideration `aria-labelledby` for displaying tooltips. Is that what you understood? It’s only used to calculate the accessible name for the element.

Comment: Why do you want to “disable” the tooltip on the polygons? Can you interact with these?

Comment: Can you please confirm whether it works in the interactive example in my answer?

Comment: I updated the answer to be more robust. I tested in Firefox and Chrome this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two misunderstandings in the question, if I got the question right.

1. ARIA attributes like `aria-labelledby` do *not* change browser behaviour like tooltips. They only control what gets exposed to assistive technology via the accessibility tree.
2. You can not have several `<title>` attributes inside one element¹.

For accessibility, there are other ways to provide an accessible name, most notably [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label), which will not generate a tooltip in the first place.

```
<svg aria-label="Title 1" viewBox="0 0 20 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="rect1" x="11" y="1" width="8" height="8"/>
</svg>
```

If the library does not allow producing this code, you can correct it later with JavaScript:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const title = svg.querySelector('title'); // only the first, topmost one
svg.setAttribute('aria-label', title.textContent);
svg.removeChild(title);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 20 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <rect id="rect1" x="11" y="1" width="8" height="8"/>
</svg>
```

---

1. Except for if they have different `lang` attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I made some edits to question that might make things clearer/reproducible

Comment: When I hover over the circle and rect I see parent tooltip in your example

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I don't believe using text instead of the element ID for aria-label will work with screen reader

Comment: [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label) does not accept an ID, it’s meant to provide the direct text contents. [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby) would reference the ID, if you have a visible element. I know that changing accessible names dynamically (after initial render) sometimes poses issues, but since the SVG originally had a title, and we’re just changing means to provide the accessible name, not the name itself, it should be fine. Should be tested.

Comment: To be sure, I also tested it with Firefox and NVDA. There is an issue around the SVG’s role, but that’s out of scope. When I add `role="img", NVDA correctly announces “Title 1, graphic”, and the tooltip is gone.

Comment: Indeed! aria-label met my needs without a title element thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can reinsert the SVG in the dom:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const clone = svg.cloneNode(true);
svg.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, svg);
```

Or do remove and add on the parent.

A minimal reproducible would be nice for further investigation.

Comment: Thanks, I made some edits to question that might make things clearer/reproducible